# Goole Maps API - Text Search New - LocationRestriction doesn't work

Tags: text-search

I'm using the API Text Search, to find several locations with general request, like "Pizza Hut", and retrieve information about opening hours.
I'd like to restrain my search by location, using the LocationRestriction filter.

I copied/pasted the exact same code as google provides, as an example.

I coded it with cURL, and here's the error message :
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: textQuery
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535

Same with Powershell, I used the exact same example as google maps, and it shows :

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:25 char:13

- $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -Hea ...
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Any clue on why Google Maps examples are not working ?
Thank you so much for your help,
Alice

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, although my error states, ""Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"circle\" at 'location_restriction': Cannot find field.", The circle field works in the nearbySearch but not for Text search. It says in the documentation that Text search supports locationRestriction https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search#location-bias. Just answered my own question: locationRestriction has to be defined as a rect Viewport. Guess I got to read a bit more... ;)